# Element.scroll() Options doesn't scroll immediately

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Element.scroll() Options doesn't scroll immediately, which creates 2 problems for me:

1. If someone click on the button scroll 2 times quickly, it doesn't scroll with 2 * scroll Units but less.
2. I can't test the method, because `Element.scrollLeft` doesn't change (See console.log below **Before** and **After**)

```js
const scrollRight = () => {
    const parent = document.querySelector('.parent');
    const scrollUnit = 100;
    console.log('Before parent.scrollLeft: ',parent.scrollLeft);
    parent.scroll({
        behavior: 'smooth',
        left: parent.scrollLeft + scrollUnit
    });
    console.log('After parent.scrollLeft: ',parent.scrollLeft);
}
```

```css
.parent{
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
.child {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  height: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  width:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="scrollRight()">Scroll right</button>
```

Comment: disable button after first click?

Comment: I need to disable button after each click for little time. Which can solve the user problem but What about testing the component?

Comment: if you change width of container console will work.

Comment: @SimoneRossaini what are you talking about ?

Comment: maybe I didn't understand the question but if you put: "width: 100px;" at .parent the console works

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear. You need to compare between console.log before and after. There is no change whereas it should be

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pjqmut6r/ <-- if you press two time console will ouput the correct log.

Comment: Melchia have you see link?

Comment: You just copied my code in fiddle. It's not working. Can't you see for every 2 console.log we have the same value ?